# heemod::how to define different initial counts for two strategies when running a model

Tags: r, rstudio, markov

is it possible to run different initial counts for two strategies in library heemod?

Let's say we have the example provided from ?run_model

```
mod1 <- define_strategy( transition = define_transition( .5, .5, .1, .9 ), define_state( cost = 543, ly = 1 ), define_state( cost = 432, ly = 1 ) )
```

and

```
mod2 <- define_strategy( transition = define_transition( .5, .5, .1, .9 ), define_state( cost = 789, ly = 1 ), define_state( cost = 456, ly = 1 ) )
```

How can we change this function

```
res2 <- run_model( mod1, mod2, cycles = 10, cost = cost, effect = ly)
```

and set mod1 c(80,20) and for mod2 c(60,40) initial counts?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It would not make sense for a cohort based Markov model, which package heemod runs. These models compare strategies on comparable groups of patients, starting out equally distributed among health states. So this function is not available.